# [ROS2] hangs forever when getting parameter for node defined in another node

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have this script

```
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

class MinimalTimer : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
  MinimalTimer()
  : Node("MinimalTimer")
  {
    node_ = std::make_shared<rclcpp::Node>("test_node");
    node_->declare_parameter("parameter_A");

    auto timer_callback = [this]() -> void {
      RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Callback!");
    };

    timer_ = this->create_wall_timer(500ms, timer_callback);
    this->declare_parameter("parameter_B");
  }

private:
  rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr timer_;
  std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node> node_;
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  auto minimal_timer = std::make_shared<MinimalTimer>();

  rclcpp::spin(minimal_timer);
  rclcpp::shutdown();

  return 0;
}
```

and I ran `ros2 run ...`.

`ros2 node list` gives

```
/MinimalTimer
/test_node
```

`ros2 param list MinimalTimer` gives

```
  parameter_B
  use_sim_time
```

but `ros param list test_node` hangs forever.

Any idea?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327654/%5Bros2%5D-hangs-forever-when-getting-parameter-for-node-defined-in-another-node/) by [ahtsan](https://answers.ros.org/users/43242/ahtsan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2019-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The example creates two nodes:`MinimalTimer` and `test_node`, but spins only one of them `rclcpp::spin(minimal_timer);`. `rclcpp::spin()` adds a node to an executor. The executor calls callbacks, like the parameter service callbacks. `test_node` must be added to an executor so the parameter service callbacks can send a response.

See [the manual composition demo](https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/dashing/composition/src/manual_composition.cpp) for an example.

```
rclcpp::executors::SingleThreadedExecutor exec;
exec.add_node(minimal_timer);
exec.add_node(minimal_timer->node_);
exec.spin();
```

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2019-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahtsan](https://answers.ros.org/users/43242/ahtsan/) on 2019-07-09**:
Thank you!